# Kubernetes service URL not responding to API call

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I've been following multiple tutorials on how to deploy my (Spring Boot) api on Minikube. I already got it (`user-service running on 8081`) working in a docker container with an `api gateway (port 8080)` and `eureka (port 8087)`, but for starters I just want it to run without those. Steps I took:

1. Push docker container or image (?) to docker hub, I don't know the proper term.
2. Create a deployment.yaml:

   ```yaml
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: kwetter-service
   spec:
     type: LoadBalancer
     selector:
       app: kwetter
     ports:
       - protocol: TCP
         port: 8080
         targetPort: 8081
         nodePort: 30070
   ---
   apiVersion: apps/v1
   kind: Deployment
   metadata:
     name: kwetter-deployment
     labels:
       app: kwetter
   spec:
     replicas: 1
     selector:
       matchLabels:
         app: kwetter
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           app: kwetter
       spec:
         containers:
           - name: user-api
             image: cazhero/s6-kwetter-backend_user:latest
             ports: 
               - containerPort: 8081 #is the port it runs on when I manually start it up
   ```
3. `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`
4. `minikube service kwetter-service`
5. It takes me to an empty site with url: `http://192.168.49.2:30070` which I thought I could use to make API calls to, but apparently not. How do I make api calls to my application running on minikube?

Get svc returns:

```
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          4d4h
kwetter-service   LoadBalancer   10.106.42.56   <pending>     8080:30070/TCP   4d
```

`describe svc kwetter-service`:

```
Name:                     kwetter-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=kwetter
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.106.42.56
IPs:                      10.106.42.56
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8081/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30070/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.4:8081
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                -------
  Normal  Type    6s    service-controller  LoadBalancer -> NodePort
```

Made an Ingress in the yaml, used `kubectl get ing`:

```
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
kwetter-ingress   <none>   *                 80      49m
```

Comment: If the answer was useful, please upvote or mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for community members.

Answer (score 0):

To make some things clear:

1. You need to have pushed your docker image `cazhero/s6-kwetter-backend_user:latest` to docker hub, check that at https://hub.docker.com/, in your personal repository.
2. What's the output of `minikube service kwetter-service`, does it print the URL `http://192.168.49.2:30070`?
3. Make sure your pod is running correctly by the following minikube command:

   ```
   # check pod status
   minikube kubectl -- get pods
   # if the pod is running, check its container logs
   minikube kubectl -- logs po kwetter-deployment-xxxx-xxxx
   ```

Comment: It doesn't print out anything, it just opens the brower and goes to `http://192.168.49.2:30070`. Pod is running, can't execute the last line though..

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai did your try to run the last line in a new comand line console?

Comment: `po` just doesn't exist

Comment: @Zheng-rongCai you should find the pod name matching the `kwetter-deployment-xxxx-xxxx` pattern, and replace the xxxx with your real string.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using LoadBalancer service, where a LoadBalancer service is the standard way to expose a service to the internet. With this method, each service gets its own IP address.

- Check external IP

  ```
  kubectl get svc
  ```
- Use the external IP and the port number in this format to access the
  application.

  ```
  http://REPLACE_WITH_EXTERNAL_IP:8080
  ```

**If you want to access the application using Nodeport (30070), use the Nodeport service instead of LoadBalancer service.**

Refer to this [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) for more information on accessing applications through Nodeport and LoadBalancer services.

Comment: Oh well...when I do get svc, the LoadBalancer says: `kwetter-service  LoadBalancer 
 10.106.42.56  <pending>  8080:30070/TCP  4d` I'll make an edit in the post for better formatting.

Comment: I see that external IP is still in pending state, try using this command `kubectl describe svc <service-name>` which gives details on warnings/errors of external IP not getting configured. Refer this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58182760/external-ip-pending-kubernetes-load-balancer) for information and can you provide details on the IP address being used in the API call i.e., http://192.168.49.2:30070

Comment: When it was still running in a docker container I could use localhost:8080, but now I'm not sure, I tried the other ip `10.106.42.56:8080` and that didn't work either. So not sure where to look for the IP (Edited post with describe svc command). 

I also added an ingress in the yaml and that one returns almost nothing either.

Comment: externalIP:port will make us map to the cluster from external sources. but 10.106.42.56 seems to be clusterIP, so we access through `10.106.42.56:8080` cluster IP from external sources and I see that external IP is not yet configured for loadbalancer, if that is configured we can access the cluster from external sources.

Comment: But how does one configure the external IP that is pending? Because the post doesn't actually say how to do that (I also don't have any error messages)

Comment: Refer to this [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110876/kubernetes-service-external-ip-pending)  for more information on resolving issues with pending external ip and this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/) for more information on load balancers.